# SSH access to AWS server works with ec2-user only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm using a stock Amazon Linux AMI and I can login fine as ec2-user. However I created a new user on the server and added the same files to new user's .ssh folder and set all the permissions correctly. I am unable to ssh for that new user, and all I see in the logs are:

: Connection closed by 213.119.15.151 port 56854 [preauth]

Is there something I need to change in the sshd_config file or anything else I need to look at?

Comment: Did you chmod 700 /home/newuser/.ssh and chmod 600 /home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys ?

Comment: I did... usually those issues will be explianed in the log file. But my logs don't indicate any permission problems.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html and are you explicitly specifying the private key using `ssh -i`? Otherwise you can debug with `ssh -vvvv`

Answer (score 0):

What @jarmod said, plus make sure /home/newuser/.ssh and /home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys are owned by newuser! (Don't ask how I know that this could be a problem :) :) :) )

Also make sure that /home/newuser is not world-writable, that would also make OpenSSH unhappy.